# What can I use to replace translate3d

Tags: css

So, the code `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` makes `position:fixed;` not work. and by removing it, I am now allowed to use `position:fixed;` again. one problem, my navigation bar was using the transform code to open, what other way can I use to make it do the same?

heres the code with the transform code, keep in mind this have been removed.

```
.nav-content {
  flex: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.nav-content.isOpen {
  transform: translate3d(220px,0,0);
}
.nav-content.isClosed {
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transforms establish a containing block even for fixed elements. There is no workaround. Either don't use transforms or fixed positioning becomes somewhat useless.

In this case, if you are only using `translate3d` to translate in X direction, you can just use relative positioning with a left offset.

```css
.nav-content {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: left .3s;
}
.nav-content.isOpen {
  left: 220px;
}
```

```css
.nav-content {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: left .3s;
  height: 200vh;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
:checked ~ .nav-content {
  left: 220px;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
<label for="toggle">Toggle</label>
<div class="nav-content">
  <div class="fixed">I am fixed</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, the solution didnt work but usefull information. gues ill have to chose to drop fixed position or to redesign the navigation bar. thanks

Comment: I can see that it works here, but not able to get it to work on my navigation, properbly because of the layout. but is there any other way to make something fixed? can I used javascript?

Comment: You probably can fake it with JS but I don't recommend it. You should fix your layout.

Comment: ye i figured that the translate3d part dont work in some browsers aswell, so the best thing is to redesign the navigation bar and keep the fixed positioning work